# Is there an android-like live wallpaper for unity?

Tags: desktop-environments, desktop-background

Is there any program which can run a 'live wallpaper' like the ones in Android? 
I've searched quite a bit but haven't found anything usable yet. [anibg](http://code.google.com/p/anibg/) looks promising, but it is not working in 12.10.

Comment: there is this PPA with an oneiric repo - I cant get it to work though... http://ilapstech.blogspot.com/2010/10/galaxy-live-wallpaper-like-compiz.html

Comment: So, were the answers below helpful for you?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a video file or a screensaver as your wallpaper with VDesk, which can be downloaded here: http://www.gnome-look.org/CONTENT/content-files/141678-VDesk_1.3.zip.

Just download the file, extract it, open a terminal window, `cd` to the folder where you extracted the archive, and run `sudo ./installer && ./VDesk`.
Next you'll get a very simple wizard which allows you to use a video file or a screensaver as your wallpaper.

[image: Setting up VDesk]

Comment: +1 There should be a 'best screenshot' badge, you'd win it.

Comment: @RobinJ this is great but is not works for videos and have some limited option but u have best among all. i am waiting for some perfect solution for this

Comment: @ RobinJ this getting two heavy system is getting hang and not workingin ubuntu 11.10

Comment: @Gaurav_Java It worked fine for me, though it's true that this solution can be quite resource hungry at times. It needs MPlayer (and some codecs?) for playing video's.

Comment: @RobinJ I tired many times its not working

Answer (score 4):

The Compiz-plugins-livewallpapers project has been abandoned by its developer, in order to be rewritten as a standalone application.
That's why you should now remove the package compiz-plugins-livewallpapers and the ppa fyrmir/compiz-plugins, and add the ppa:fyrmir/livewallpaper-stable and then install the package livewallpaper.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fyrmir/compiz-plugins
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-livewallpapers
```

Then launch ccsm (compizconfig-settings-manager).
Enable the livewallpaper plugin and then Galaxy or Nexus plugin.

Check the autostart option to enable it on session startup.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/live-wallpaper-for-ubuntu ? It is apparently recommended to not use this on portable devices, or the battery power might 'disappear faster than Cherries around Pacman'... :D

Answer (score 2):

Animated backgrounds are already supported and Ubuntu already ships with some example of wallpapers that change through the day. The only thing missing (as far as I know) is a tool to create such wallpapers.

You can find an example in `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/background-1.xml`.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the OP is looking for. They probably want a wallpaper that can actually be seen moving in real time, not just change at specified times.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enlightenment (window manager) supports animated backgrounds. Those are quite heavy on the CPU though.
   http://www.enlightenment.org/
2. Conky can be set up so that it draws images over the current bg.
   Official: http://conky.sourceforge.net/
   Nice examples: http://pieter.blinkenshell.org/blog/?tag=conky
3. Xplanetfx is also a choice (it's a GUI that controls xplanet). This is limited to rendering planet, but it's quite easy to use with the GUI.
   http://mein-neues-blog.de/xplanetfx/

Comment: Would be nice if you linked your hints to some backgroud information!

Answer (score -1):

FOR UBUNTU 11.04

You can try this Compiz plugin which simulates Android's Galaxy Live Wallpaper (instructions from [this OMG! Ubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/animated-galaxy-desktop-wallpaper-for-ubuntu/)):

> #### Install
>
> Installing the plugin is relatively straightforward. The instructions
> below assume you already have Compiz and the Compiz settings manager
> installed.
>
> Open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal) and enter the
> following two lines separately, hitting the enter key after each.
>
> - *sudo add-apt-repository **ppa:ilap/lwp***
> - *sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-livewallpapers*
>
> Proceed to enable and configure the plugin: -
>
> 1. Right click on the Desktop and choose ‘Change Desktop Background’
> 2. Press the “Add” button
> 3. Enter “*/usr/share/backgrounds*” in “Location” field. Hit the return/enter key
> 4. Select “Space_by_ilap.jpg”
> 5. Press “Open” followed by “Close”
>
> After the background is changed you need to enable the “Galaxy Live
> Wallpaper” plugin via the CompizConfig Settings Manager. Launch it
> from:
>
> ```
> **Systems -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager**
> ```
>
> The Compiz Configuration Settings Manager window will open. In the
> left-hand side pane select “Live Wallpapers” and check/enable ‘Galaxy
> Live Wallpaper’.
>
> Toggle the live galaxy effect by pressing the “Super” (Windows logo
> button) and F4 keys in unison.
>
> #### Galaxy Live Wallpaper in action
>
> You can delve in the live wallpaper settings accessible through the
> CompizConfig Settings Manager to further tweak how the wallpaper
> behaves.

Comment: Have you actually tested this on oneiric? It looks like you've just copied the instructions from some website and it applies to 11.04

Comment: i tried this it is not working on ubuntu 11.10