# Application as desktop background in Ubuntu

Tags: java, desktop-background

I was thinking, if there is any way to set, for example, a java application as my desktop background? I'd love to see Lotka-Volterra Predator-Prey Model visualization on my desktop.
An example of this program:
http://en.alife.pl/predators-and-prey-the-Lotka-Volterra-model

Answer (score 0):

I think **[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80667/is-there-an-android-like-live-wallpaper-for-unity)** can be the beginning of an answer for you :)

If I understand correctly, you basically want ot create a live wallpaper

[Here are a few live wallpapers you might like.](http://refugeeks.com/RefuGeeks/2012/08/use-live-wallpapers-in-ubuntu/)
Isearched quickly, but couldn't find any ressource to create your own though.